# Can I use inner query into inner query for 3rd max or nth max id?

Tags: mysql, sql

My query is given below:

```
select max(id)
from crmtestregis
where id < (select max(id) from  crmtestregis where id <
    (select max(id) from crmtestregis));
```

Please suggest inner query is best or some other option is best?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` here:

```
SELECT id
FROM crmtestregis
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 2;
```

The above query would return the third record from the top, with an ordering of `id` descending.

If you instead wanted the third highest *unique* value, then we can use `DISTINCT` and a similar query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM crmtestregis
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
OFFSET 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id FROM crmtestregis
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT n-1,1;
```

Replace n with 'N' max ID (MySQL)